# Select and display on three edit texts in SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, methods

can somebody help me on my method/db/query. The thing is here i want to pass the data on my database and search then display. I am intend to pass a unique key and 3 edittext so on my db and db is the one who set the text on edittext depends on my unique key.

Here is my sample db code (I try but I know it is wrong):

I call db (controller) on my oncreate using this code:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String descpe = b.getString("pedesc");

    context = this;
    controller = new DB_ST(this,"",null,1);

    controller.list_pw_details(descpe, etDesc, etPass, etNote);
```

Database method (query):

```
public void list_pw_details(String unqdesc, EditText desc, EditText pass, EditText note){
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PASSWALL WHERE PW_DESC='"+unqdesc+"'", null);
    desc.setText("");
    pass.setText("");
    note.setText("");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        desc.append(cursor.getString(1));
        pass.append(cursor.getString(2));
        note.append(cursor.getString(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: can the data retrieved ? You should not pass the EditText..pass String instead

Comment: i have working code when i passing a textview and displays. I only tried to pass edit text and not sure if it is working

Comment: post the code where it start to invoke list_pw_details();

Comment: please check i edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void list_pw_details(String unqdesc, EditText desc, EditText pass, EditText note){

        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PASSWALL WHERE PW_DESC='"+unqdesc+"'", null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
         while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();  // your object class ,get and set method
                contact.setName((cursor.getString(0));
                contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setMobile(cursor.getString(2));
                desc.setText(contact.getName());
                pass.setText(contact.getXXX());
                note.setText(contact.getXXX());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: btw what are those // .... below? and how about EditText pass and EditText note thank youuu

Comment: Do you have bean class which include set and get method ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped.